# MySQL- Invalid default value for 'lasttime'

Tags: mysql

```
SQL sorgusu:

CREATE TABLE online(

idonline İNT( 10 ) UNSİGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ip VARCHAR( 16 ) ,
domain VARCHAR( 100 ) ,
FKiduyeler İNT( 10 ) UNSİGNED,
lasttime TİMESTAMP DEFAULT  'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
PRIMARY KEY ( idonline ) ,
KEY online_index3587( ip ) ,
KEY online_index3588( domain ) ,
KEY online_index3592( FKiduyeler ) ,
KEY online_index3604( lasttime )
);

MySQL çıktısı: Belgeler

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'lasttime'
```

Before everthing sorry about my english; when l upload my db ,l got this proglem.Please help me.Thanks

Comment: See the manual under TIMESTAMP, and then get back to us.

Comment: `lasttime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ... ditch the `I` with a dot above it, and remove the single quotes.

Comment: thank for help but l didn't understand you .possible to show me

Comment: For those not speaking Turkish: *sorgusu* = query, *hata* = error, *çıktısı* = output, *belgeler* = documents.

Answer (score 1):

- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`
- `I` instead of `İ` at multiple places.

---

```
CREATE TABLE `online`(

idonline INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
ip VARCHAR( 16 ) ,
domain VARCHAR( 100 ) ,
FKiduyeler INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED,
lasttime TIMESTAMP DEFAULT  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, -- lose the single quotes here
PRIMARY KEY ( idonline ) ,
KEY online_index3587( ip ) ,
KEY online_index3588( domain ) ,
KEY online_index3592( FKiduyeler ) ,
KEY online_index3604( lasttime )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for helping, but when l do that I'm getting this problem:

> CREATE TABLE visitor_chats ( visitor_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
>   browser_id varchar(32) NOT NULL, visit_id varchar(32) NOT NULL,
>   chat_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, fullname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   email varchar(255) NOT NULL, company varchar(255) NOT NULL, status
>   tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, typing tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   waiting tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, area_code varchar(255) NOT NULL,
>   first_active int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, last_active int(10) unsigned
>   NOT NULL, qpenalty int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, request_operator
>   varchar(32) NOT NULL, request_group varchar(32) NOT NULL, question
>   varchar(255) NOT NULL, customs text NOT NULL, allocated int(11)
>   unsigned NOT NULL, internal_active tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   internal_closed tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, internal_declined
>   tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, external_active tinyint(1) unsigned NOT
>   NULL, external_close tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL, exit int(11) [...]

*MySQL error*

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'exit int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY
>   (visitor_id,browser_id,visit_id,c' at line 26"

Comment: `EXIT` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL, you should not use it as a field name. Consider posting your comments below the answer you are commenting, so that the answerer could be automatically notified of your reply.